Mapping the reads
I am working on determining the gene abundance and mapping the reads using bwa and samtools. Below are the steps I am following. Could you please confirm if these steps are correct or suggest any improvements?
Please take a look at the code here
Thank you
Feedback regarding reads mapping to a fasta file (containing two gene sequences)
